# Display of MathJax in titles of questions and answers on user profile lists is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, profile-page

Starting from a user's profile page, if you list all of their questions or all of their answers, posts whose titles contain complex MathJax formulae are not displayed properly.

There are some extreme examples, but I don't want to embarrass anybody else, so here is an example from [the list of my own questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/213690/calum-gilhooley?tab=questions):

[image: example of broken MathJax display]

Comment: Technically, it's an issue with the Activity page, not the Profile page.  It's an old MathJax issue that was fixed years ago, but now it's back and much worse than before.

Comment: @RandomVariable True. (There isn't a tag for the user activity page, though.)

Comment: i also have this problem. seems to related to mathjax in title.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Unfortunately it looks like this has not quite been completely stamped out - see the "reviewed edit" in [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/f3AC5Km) from today. Should I also report this somewhere else?

Comment: @KReiser Interesting. I'm not exactly sure, you could post another answer in the meta thread (which is already extremely loaded so might not get much notice) or a Meta.SE question linking to the thread.

Comment: @KReiser That seems to be an issue in the "All actions" tab of the "Activity" page. If I'm not mistaken, it is the same issue that has been [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474) by [User Sycorax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/320588/sycorax) on Meta SE (see the "Update" added in revision 8, in particular), and that report is currently marked [status-planned].

Comment: @TheAmplitwist excellent, thank you.

Comment: As of today, MathJax is also not displaying correctly on the main Activity page.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  It's marked as "status-completed" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375745).

Comment: @RandomVariable Oh, I see! This  surely *should* get renewed attention, then. Perhaps another Meta SE post with the [regression] tag would be best...?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  I'm not sure what the best course of action would be, but I guess anything that attracts more attention to the problem would be good. I notified a MathJax developer (Davide Cervone) that the issue has returned.

Comment: Another report recently added on [metase]: [LaTeX formula have extraneous line breaks on the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378009).