# Broken MathJax formatting on activity page

Tags: bug, mathjax, titles, recent-activity

Here is a screenshot from [my](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/811225?tab=topactivity) activity page:
[image]

running Google Chrome Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

However the browser or the version doesn't seem to matter, tested same thing on Firefox, Waterfox, Edge (running stable main line).

It is pretty evident that the MathJax is leaking out of the box (when it shouldn't). I found a similar [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34391/811225) which has now been marked [status-completed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) but looks like this question deals specifically with multiline formatting, so I think it is not the same bug.

Comment: I don't think this is only for multiline formatting. I also experience the same bug, specifically, for $a_n = a_i + (n - i)d$ which breaks to look like $a_n = a_i \\ + (n - i)d$.

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before. The question title is entirely made up of Mathjax and the software can't find a natural break between words to start a new line.

Comment: @PeterPhipps I don't think that explains what I see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuctx.png), under the Bookmarks heading on my activity page. There seems to be plenty of [horizontal] room for a proper MathJax rendering of that title, as is illustrated by the one above it.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I was refering to the screenshot in the question where a single line of Mathjax goes across the page, which is what I thought the question was about.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley   That issue was fixed a couple months ago, but it came back shortly thereafter in some places.  I notified a Stack Exchange developer a couple weeks ago, but I have not received a response.  The issue still appears to be marked as "status-completed."

Comment: 1 year anniversary